# Forming rules from facts. Rule based programming

Tags: rule-engine, inference, clips, jess

Learning Clips, while I don't mind the syntax I'm finding it difficult to derive rules from facts. Is there a tip on how to structure rules given a knowledge base? 
A non trivial example would be nice, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this is the entire field of "knowledge engineering;" it's really as broad a question as "given a domain, how do I architect application software for that domain?" Whole books have been written on this topic. Here are three that treat this topic well IMO: Peter Norvig's ["Artificial Intelligence, A Modern Approach"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136042597), Giarratano and Riley's ["Expert Systems: Principles and Programming"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0534384471), and my ["Jess In Action"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1930110898).

Comment: Thanks, I guess it is that broad. I will have a look at the links provided.